# How to implement a scalar list-field type of a schema.prisma in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am trying to use a MySql database with GraphQL. The models in the schema.prisma contain list-fields, i.e. object data types. Since MySql does not support scalar-lists, how can I implement the `links` field of the following model in a MySql table?

```
model User {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  email       String  @unique
  password    String  
  links       Link[]
}
```

Comment: Examples are shown here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database-workflows/foreign-keys/mysql

Comment: Thanks Bill, that helped, I figured it out.

Comment: @maraxai If you figured it out, can you provide and answer please?

Comment: Such a shame this gets ignored...